# MySql JOIN query with OR clause very slow

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.id, b.from, b.to FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.from OR a.id = b.to;
```

which is extremely slow.

If I remove the OR clause and run each query separately then the both queries execute under 1 second.

```
SELECT a.id, b.from, b.to FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.from;
SELECT a.id, b.from, b.to FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.to;
```

How can I speed up the original query (set up indexes) or redesign the query itself?

Comment: Can you provide MySql damp of table?

Comment: Questions about performance generally require proper DDLs and an EXPLAIN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using union?

```
SELECT a.id, b.from, b.to FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.from
UNION
SELECT a.id, b.from, b.to FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.to
```

Comment: Not quite the solution but enough to fix my query. I'm using the union to reduce the number of rows for the join which happens on a outer select something like: SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... UNION SELECT) INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following instead.  Just join to `b` twice:

```
SELECT a.id, b.from, b2.to 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.from
INNER JOIN b b2 ON a.id = b2.to;
```

You may have to use LEFT JOIN instead if you don't always have a record for both cases.